# How to find the selected date is Saturday or Sunday in sqlite manager

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to find if the selected date from my table is a Saturday or Sunday in sql. I'm using SQLiteManager. If anyone could help, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strftime()`:

```
select (case when strftime('%w', datecol) in ('0', '6') then 1 else 0 end) as is_weekend
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this query gives the same output for both weekend days and weekdays. Could you please give some suggestion?

Comment: @RuwaniSangeetha . . . Check what the `strftime()` class is returning on your data.  This is the right syntax for what you want (https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: I checked strftime() and your query gives the answer. Thanks a lot!!! -:)